# Fill in NULL column values with lag(N) values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a simple table that is missing values for the "somebody" column.  I want to fill in the NULL values with previous values in ascending order from the id field, but not the descending values (items in the past may be different).  For the sake of the experiment (my actual query is far more complex), I can not simply use an UPDATE query to fill the table, I have to do this as a SELECT.

```
CREATE TABLE lag_test (id serial primary key, natural_key integer, somebody text);

INSERT INTO lag_test(natural_key, somebody)
VALUES (1, NULL), (1, 'Kirk'), (1, NULL), (2, 'Roybal'), (2, NULL), (2, NULL);
```

Sample code creates a table like this:

```
id  natural_key  somebody
--  -----------  --------
1   1            NULL
2   1            Kirk
3   1            NULL
4   2            Roybal
5   2            NULL
6   2            NULL
```

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT id,
       natural_key,
       COALESCE(somebody, lag(somebody) OVER (PARTITION BY natural_key)) somebody
FROM lag_test
ORDER BY natural_key, id;
```

Which returns this:

```
id  natural_key  somebody
--  -----------  --------
1   1            NULL
2   1            Kirk
3   1            Kirk
4   2            Roybal
5   2            Roybal
6   2            NULL
```

I would like it to return this:

```
id  natural_key  somebody
--  -----------  --------
1   1            NULL
2   1            Kirk
3   1            Kirk
4   2            Roybal
5   2            Roybal
6   2            Roybal
```

The basic question is:  How do I get lag() to work N rows into the past so that the row id:6,natural_key:2 receives a value for the "somebody" column?

I'm working with PG 9.3.4.

Update:
Reading the docs, I found out that lag takes an optional parameter [offset] that I was able to use to some extent.  Hope somebody can help me refine this:

```
SELECT id,
       natural_key,
       COALESCE(somebody,
                lag(somebody, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY natural_key),
                lag(somebody, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY natural_key),
                lag(somebody, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY natural_key)
               ) somebody
FROM lag_test
ORDER BY natural_key, id;
```

This solves the problem for the limited test set shown in the OP.  The real question has not yet been answered.

Edit 2:

I also figured out this little gem.

```
SELECT id, natural_key, 
  regexp_replace(string_agg(somebody, '|') OVER (ORDER BY id)::text, '^.*\|', '', 'g') somebody 
FROM lag_test 
ORDER BY natural_key, id;
```

Which only works for data that doesn't contain a pipe "|" symbol.   Kinda hacky, but performance is good.

Comment: Adequate update is easy in anonymous code block. Would you accept such a soultion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adequate update", sorry.

Comment: The update you want to do.

Comment: I can't use an UPDATE statement.  The example is very simple, but the actual use case is very complex.  I would appreciate an answer that related to window functions, not table updates.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. I am affraid a solution with lag() will be very complicated. Still it is simple with user defined function.

Comment: No harm, no foul.  I appreciate the effort.  I've seen you answer a lot of PostgreSQL questions.

Comment: @klin: I would be interested in learning what the complicated LAG solution looks like. Personally, I don't see how it can be used here at all, but I must admit that I am no PostgreSQL expert and my understanding of LAG and some other window functions can still be considered basic. However, I tried hard to avoid a subquery in this situation and couldn't succeed. If you do have any idea at all, please share.

Comment: @AndriyM: I thought about a try with a recursive cte. I should have written *it would be complicated if possible* rather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one with the correct output -- according to what you show. To extend the test, I entered a few more values creating two different names with a gap between them.

```
CREATE TABLE lag_test(
  id serial primary key,
  natural_key integer,
  somebody text);

INSERT  INTO lag_test( natural_key, somebody )
VALUES  (1, NULL), (1, 'Kirk'), (1, NULL), (1, NULL), (1, 'James'), (1, NULL),
        (2, 'Roybal'), (2, NULL), (2, NULL),
        (3, NULL), (3, 'Truman'), (3, NULL), (3, NULL);
```

I can't figure out if this will ever work with analytics (not using LAG anyway), but here is one solution which has one join and one subquery. Fairly simple really.

```
SELECT  lt.ID ID, lt.Natural_key,
        CASE WHEN lt.Somebody IS NULL
            THEN lt1.Somebody
            ELSE lt.Somebody END SomeBody
  FROM  lag_test lt
  LEFT JOIN lag_test lt1
    ON  lt1.ID =(
        SELECT  MAX( ID )
          FROM  lag_test
         WHERE  Natural_key = lt.Natural_key
           and  ID < lt.ID
           AND  SomeBody IS NOT NULL);
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5502b/1/0) sandbox.

Comment: This provides exactly what I asked for, thank you.  The lag_test "table" in the example is actually a very complex query, which I rewrote into a CTE so I could reference the results twice to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it but try this:

```
SELECT lt.id, lt.natural_key, l.somebody from lag_test lt inner join (select 
lt.natural_key, lt.somebody from lag_test lt inner join (select MAX(id) as LastID, 
somebody from lag_test WHERE NOT somebody is null GROUP BY somebody) as lson 
lt.id=ls.LastID) as l on lt.natural_key=l.natural_key
```

May not be the most compact way but it works for me.

This is the Result

```
id  natural_key somebody
----------------------------
1   1   Kirk
2   1   Kirk
3   1   Kirk
4   1   Kirk
5   2   Roybal
6   2   Roybal
7   2   Roybal
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer.  It didn't work directly (column reference "somebody" is ambiguous LINE 3: (select natural_key, somebody from lag_test lt inner join). I see the strategy of where you are going anyway.  Two issues with this: 1) I didn't want to backfill the row 1:1:Kirk.  That one should still be 1:1:NULL.  And 2) I was hoping that the question would be resolved using lag() not a subquery fill.  The actual base query is insanely complex and has millions of rows, so the subquery fill strategy takes hours to complete.

Comment: I suposse your real case is somehow different from the one you post. Why didn't work?